# Trying to write something in one activity and reading it in the next activity

Tags: java, android

Im currently creating a barber application and at the moment, on my landing page i have a button that when clicked it will bring up a popup window for the user to enter their name and contact number

Now what i want to do is when the user clicks view appointments it shows what appointments there are on the page name ContactUs.java

So here is my Landing.java page

```
package ie.app.barbershop;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class Landing extends AppCompatActivity{

    public Button buttonProducts;
    public Button button4;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_landing);
        readRecords();
        countRecords();

        buttonProducts = findViewById(R.id.buttonProducts);
        button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);

        Button buttonCreateAppointment = findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAppointment);
        buttonCreateAppointment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerCreateAppointment());

        buttonProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Landing.this, Products.class));
            }
        });

        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Landing.this, ContactUs.class));
            }
        });


    }


    public void readRecords() {

        LinearLayout linearLayoutRecords = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRecords);
        linearLayoutRecords.removeAllViews();

        List<ObjectAppointment> appointments = new TableControllerAppointments(this).read();

        if (appointments.size() > 0) {

            for (ObjectAppointment obj : appointments) {


                String fullName = obj.fullName;
                int contactNumber = obj.contactNumber;

                String textViewContents = fullName + " - " + contactNumber;

                TextView textViewAppointmentItem= new TextView(this);
                textViewAppointmentItem.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
                textViewAppointmentItem.setText(textViewContents);
                textViewAppointmentItem.setTag(Integer.toString(contactNumber));

                linearLayoutRecords.addView(textViewAppointmentItem);
            }

        }

        else {

            TextView locationItem = new TextView(this);
            locationItem.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            locationItem.setText("No records yet.");

            linearLayoutRecords.addView(locationItem);
        }

    }





    public void countRecords(){

        int recordCount = new TableControllerAppointments(this).count();

        TextView textViewRecordCount = findViewById(R.id.textViewRecordCount);
        textViewRecordCount.setText(recordCount + " records found.");

    }

}
```

This is my ContactUs.Java page(This should be called ViewAppointments.java but it was originally meant to be a contact us page)

```
package ie.app.barbershop;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ContactUs extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_us);
    }

}
```

This is my onclicklistenerCreateAppointment.java page

```
package ie.app.barbershop;

import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OnClickListenerCreateAppointment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public ObjectAppointment objectAppointment;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

        final Context context = view.getRootView().getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.appointment_input_form, null, false);
        final EditText editTextFullName = formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextFullName);
        final EditText editTextContactNumber = formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextContactNumber);

        ObjectAppointment objectAppointment = new ObjectAppointment();


        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)




                .setView(formElementsView)
                .setTitle("Create Appointment")
                .setPositiveButton("Add",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                                String fullname = editTextFullName.getText().toString();
                                String contactno = editTextContactNumber.getText().toString();

                                ((Landing) context).countRecords();
                                ((Landing) context).readRecords();

                                dialog.cancel();
                            }

                        }).show();

            boolean createSuccessful = new TableControllerAppointments(context).create(objectAppointment);

                if(createSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Appointment Information was saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to save appointment information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
```

And this is my TableControllerAppointments.java

```
package ie.app.barbershop;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TableControllerAppointments extends DatabaseHandler {

    public TableControllerAppointments(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public boolean create(ObjectAppointment objectAppointments) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("fullname", objectAppointments.fullName);
        values.put("contactno", objectAppointments.contactNumber);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        boolean createSuccessful = db.insert("appointments", null, values) > 0;
        db.close();

        return createSuccessful;
    }



    public List<ObjectAppointment> read() {

        List<ObjectAppointment> recordsList = new ArrayList<>();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Appointments ORDER BY id DESC";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String fullName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fullname"));
                int contactNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("contactno")));

                ObjectAppointment objectAppointment = new ObjectAppointment();
                objectAppointment.fullName = fullName;
                objectAppointment.contactNumber = contactNumber;

                recordsList.add(objectAppointment);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return recordsList;
    }

    public int count() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM appointments";
        int recordCount = db.rawQuery(sql, null).getCount();
        db.close();

        return recordCount;
    }
}
```

Any other info you need im more than happy to provide if i have forgotten something.

Im sorry if its something small and stupid im missing

Comment: You mean you want to send data from one activity to another?

Comment: Yes @Sagar sorry, So basically when the user inputs their name and number i want to be able to read it in the viewappointments

Comment: Are you able to take input from the user?

Comment: @Sagar Yup the user can enter their name and number but it seems to save each record all along the side of the screen as null 0